# Setting up SSL Certificate using mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, ssl, https, mod-wsgi

I have developed a Django 1.8 application using Python 3.3. I am trying to deploy the application on a university dedicated server with Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo). (Note: RHEL does not let me install newer versions of Django and Python)

I had difficulty with installing mod_wsgi using the RHEL Apache and I ended up installing:

```
pip install -U mod_wsgi-httpd
pip install mod_wsgi
```

Everything works perfectly when I use the following setup:

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only --port=80 --user=iman --group=root --server-root=/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80
```

However, when I want to setup HTTPS, using the following setup does not return any error message, but the website does not show up neither with http:// nor with https:// prefixes.

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --setup-only --port=80 --user=iman --group=root --server-root=/etc/mod_wsgi-express-80 --https-only --https-port=443 --ssl-certificate-file=/etc/sslcert/iman.crt --ssl-certificate-key-file=/etc/sslcert/private/iman.key --ssl-ca-certificate-file=/etc/sslcert/certs/ca-bundle.crt --server-name=iman123.university.edu
```

Here are helpful resources that I found about mod_wsgi:

[mod_wsgi docs](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/index.html)

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi)

[Running HTTPS and client authentication with mod_wsgi-express](https://gist.github.com/GrahamDumpleton/b79d336569054882679e)

[pip install mod_wsgi-express left out mod_ssl.so](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/uH-NGPogKFY)

Thank you so much for your time and concern and apologies in advance if I am doing something wrong.